# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' in code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am currently working on a linkedin scraping project for academic purposes , i'm following a tutorial that i found on google , the first segment of the code is the automated connection , next i am trying to access linkedin profiles and scrape data , what i don't understand is why do i get this error above?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import csv``
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import parameters 
from parsel import Selector
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidArgumentException




# Creating a csv file to stock profile information
with open('profiles.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Name'   ,   'Job Title'    ,    'Company'    ,     'College',     'Location'      ,    'URL']) 
    


# specifies the path to the chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/azizb/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

# driver.get method() will navigate to a page given by the URL address
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')
time.sleep(0.5)

# locate email form by_class_name
username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input__input')


# send_keys() to simulate key strokes
username.send_keys(parameters.linkedin_username)
time.sleep(0.5)


# locate password form by_class_id
password = driver.find_element_by_id('session_password')

# send_keys() to simulate key strokes
password.send_keys(parameters.linkedin_password)
time.sleep(0.5)

# locate submit button by_class_name
log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sign-in-form__submit-button')


# .click() to mimic button click
log_in_button.click()
time.sleep(0.5)

driver.get('https:www.google.com')
time.sleep(3)

# locate search form by_name
search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

# send_keys() to simulate the search text key strokes
search_query.send_keys(parameters.search_query)
time.sleep(0.5)


# .send_keys() to simulate the return key 
search_query.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(3)


# locate URL by_class_name
linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('iUh30')
# continuing on from before
linkedin_urls = [url.text for url in linkedin_urls]
time.sleep(0.5)
print(linkedin_urls)
driver.get('https://uk.linkedin.com/in/pauljgarner')

driver.page_source
linkedin_urls = [url.text for url in linkedin_urls]
time.sleep(0.5)

for linkedin_url in linkedin_urls:

   # get the profile URL 
   driver.get(linkedin_url)

   # add a 5 second pause loading each URL
   time.sleep(5)

   # assigning the source code for the webpage to variable sel
   sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source) 

# terminates the application
driver.quit()

# xpath to extract the text from the class containing the name
name = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class,"pv-top-card-section__name")]/text()').extract_first()
if name:
    name = name.strip()


# xpath to extract the text from the class containing the job title
job_title = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class,"pv-top-card-section__headline")]/text()').extract_first()

if job_title:
    job_title = job_title.strip()


# xpath to extract the text from the class containing the company
company = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class,"pv-top-card-v2-section__entity-name pv-top-card-v2-section__company-name")]/text()').extract_first()

if company:
    company = company.strip()


# xpath to extract the text from the class containing the college
college = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class,"pv-top-card-v2-section__entity-name pv-top-card-v2-section__school-name")]/text()').extract_first()

if college:
    college = college.strip()


# xpath to extract the text from the class containing the location
location = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class,"pv-top-card-section__location")]/text()').extract_first()

if location:
    location = location.strip()


linkedin_url = driver.current_url
# printing the output to the terminal
print('\n')
print('Name: ' + name)
print('Job Title: ' + job_title)
print('Company: ' + company)
print('College: ' + college)
print('Location: ' + location)
print('URL: ' + linkedin_url)
print('\n')
# defining new variable passing two parameters
writer = csv.writer(open(parameters.file_name, 'wb'))

# writerow() method to the write to the file object
writer.writerow(['Name','Job Title','Company','College', 'Location','URL'])
# function to ensure all key data fields have a value
def validate_field(field):# if field is present pass if field:pass
# if field is not present print text else:
       field = 'No results'
       return field
# validating if the fields exist on the profile
name = validate_field(name)
job_title = validate_field(job_title)
company = validate_field(company)
college = validate_field(college)
location = validate_field(location)
linkedin_url = validate_field(linkedin_url)
```

I need help , thanks !

Comment: Probably that line.
```linkedin_urls = [url.text for url in linkedin_urls]```
remove ```.text```

Comment: I tried that , it returns this error , selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string

Comment: What is ```linkedin_urls```

Comment: linkedin urls is an attribut that i have put in the url of the linkedin profiles when i do a search query , which is this one  ---->  linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('iUh30') will retrieve the url from the class name in the google results page

Comment: but i need to convert that url to text format , in the tutorial i'm following it works for him , but i don't know what's the problem for me here

Comment: You should now it's type list str etc.....

Comment: I don't understand what you mean , perhaps more clarification ? thanks for your effort and time